# SQL Server backup to Azure stopped working after moving DB files

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, sql-server-2014, database-backups

I have a database in SQL Server 2014 on premises. For that database I have a backup to Azure storage configured using `smart_admin.sp_set_db_backup` procedure.

Recently I had to move the database files from one disk to another. I detached database, moved files, reattached it.

After that my backup stopped working. The function `smart_admin.fn_backup_db_config` shows that database backup record exists but database marked as `is_dropped = 1`

Any attempt to enable or disable backup for this database fails with error:

> SQL Server Managed Backup to Windows Azure cannot configure the database, 'DATABASE_NAME', because it either does not exist or is offline.

Any way I can remove backup configuration information and create a new one? One of the ideas I found is rename the database, but I cannot do that in production.

Comment: rename the database and set backup again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Vad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31889265/5339886) is close, but there can be more than one record in `autoadmin_managed_databases` for a given `db_name`.  You need to get the last record, which is the one with the max `autoadmin_id`.  I picked the wrong one, and SQL Server repopulated the `drop_date` after I ran `smart_admin.sp_set_db_backup` or the 15 minute interval ran.

```sql
use msdb;
go

update [dbo].[autoadmin_managed_databases]
set drop_date = null
where [autoadmin_id]= (select max(autoadmin_id)
                       from [dbo].[autoadmin_managed_databases] 
                       where db_name = '<DROPPPED_DATABASE_NAME>')
go
```

Comment: That's right. There can be more than one record, so need to use MAX().

Answer (score 0):

> Managed Backups - is_dropped flag set to Yes after detaching database
>   and reattaching DB

Rename the database and set up managed backup again.

[Reference](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/98aec831-5f60-46b6-900c-7b0b64fd03d4/sql-2014-managed-backups-isdropped-flag-set-to-yes-after-detaching-database-and-reattaching-db?forum=sqldatabaseengine)

Comment: I understand that. However I cannot rename production database. Any other way?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned earlier I was not allowed to rename the database on the Production. So I found where it's marked as dropped and changed the value. That helped. Automated backups for the database started working again. IMO what happened looks like a bug in SQL Server 2014.

```
use msdb;
go

update [dbo].[autoadmin_managed_databases]
set drop_date = null
where [db_name] = '<DROPPED_DATABASE_NAME>'
go
```